# Laravel validation: how to get optional fields in the validated result array?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

i’m validating request with required and optional fields.  When the request does not contain the optional field, it’s skipped and not returned in the validated() function, how can i get the optional field with empty string value in the returned array?

```
input is [‘field_1’ => ‘test’]

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    ‘field_1’ => [‘required’],
    ‘field_2’ => [‘string’]
]);
dd($validator->validated());

current output is [‘field_1’ => ‘test’]

desire output [‘field_1’ => ‘test’, ‘field_2’ => ‘’]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `field_2` in the data for it to validate, so it couldn't return what isn't there.

You could ask the Request for these fields though:

```
$request->all(['field_1', 'field_2']);
```

Or assign your validation rules to an array then you can use the array keys from it:

```
$rules = [
    'field_1' => '...',
    'field_2' => '...',
];

...

$vals = $request->all(array_keys($rules));
dd($vals);
```

Comment: thank you, second option is the closest to what i need

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version of laravel you're using, but my answer is valid for several laravel versions. You can check before validation if `field_2` is set and react if not. The next step is adding `nullable` as validation rule to `field_2`, e.g.

```php
if (!isset($request->field_2)) {
    $request->merge(['field_2' => null]); // or even ['field_2' => '']
}

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'field_1' => ['required'],
    'field_2' => ['nullable', 'string']
]);
```

More information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields

Comment: thank you, this is a valid answer as well but i selected the other answer since i have a lot of optional fields to deal with